# Change <input> Types and Attributes for a Form Used in a CreateView and UpdateView

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm experimenting with a Django 1.4.6 project for tracking sales leads. I want this to be mobile-friendly, so I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (still on version 2.3.2) with [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.rtfd.org/). According to [this article](http://baymard.com/labs/touch-keyboard-types), the best way to do e-mail fields is `<input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">` and the best way to do date fields is `<input type="date">`. None of these attributes are implemented by default with Django and I'm wondering how best to go about implementing them. Here is the relevant code (simplified):

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Lead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    initial_contact_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, UpdateView
from .models import Lead


class LeadAdd(CreateView):
    model = Lead

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeadAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Add a Lead'
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lead_list')


class LeadEdit(LeadAdd, UpdateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeadEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Edit a Lead'
        return context


class LeadList(ListView):
    model = Lead
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import *


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', view=LeadList.as_view(), name='lead_list'),
    url(r'^add/$', view=LeadAdd.as_view(), name='lead_add'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', view=LeadEdit.as_view(), name='lead_edit'),
)
```

**lead_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="." method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form|crispy}}

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a field template to do this ([see the docs on Field](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/1.1.1/tags.html)):

```
Field('email', template="custom-email.html")
```

OR create a custom widget. There is an [abstract class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget) you can use, but one of the existing predefined widgets should work:

```
# widgets.py
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

class EmailInput(TextInput):
    input_type = 'email'
```

So it might look like this in your view:

```
class LeadAdd(CreateView):
    model = Lead
    form_class = LeadAddForm
    ...
```

And then that LeadAddForm class would have your custom widget defined:

```
from . import widgets

LeadAddForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(
        ...
        widget = widgets.EmailInput,
        ...
    )
```

Or you can set the widget in the **init**:

```
class LeadAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeadAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['email'].widget = widgets.EmailInput()
```

You should be able to set the extra attributes (autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off") using the crispy form config:

```
Field('email', autocapitalize="off", autocorrect="off")
```

Answer (score 7):

The simpler option:

`forms.py`:

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
             Fieldset('Enter the following information',
                      'name',
                      Field('email', type="email",
                                     autocapitalize="off",
                                     autocorrect="off"),
                      Field('initial_contact_date', type="date")),
             FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Create Lead'),
                Button('cancel', 'Cancel')
            )
        )
```

In your `views.py`:

```
class LeadAdd(CreateView):
    model = Lead
    success_url = reverse('lead_list')
    form_class = LeadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeadAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Add a Lead'
        return context

class LeadEdit(LeadAdd, UpdateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeadEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Edit a Lead'
        return context
```

In your template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>

        {% crispy form %}

{% endblock content %}
```